# what is the way to represent the bounding box coordinates?

Tags: detection, bounding-box

how many there way to represent the bounding box and how they represent and calculate?

 can you show some examples and the way to represent the bounding box to calculate?

ex) (X1,Y1,X2,Y2) and how to calcuate

Comment: Are your boxes axis-aligned? Or can your bounding boxes rotate?

Comment: The way to represent the bounding box.  not the rotate. Yolo should be has there own way to represent the bouding box